# How to copy a document automatically

Tags: document-library

Is it possible for a user with site administrator access, to configure a document library, so that when a document is uploaded into it, it is copied automatically to another document library & folder?

This is initially in 2007, but later in 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest no-code solution is to create a workflow with SharePoint Designer that leverages the Copy List Item action. Study this blog post for inspiration: http://blogs.salmanghani.info/?p=522.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done programmatically by implementing [custom event handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/05/part-1-event-handlers-everything-you-need-to-know-about-microsoft-office-sharepoint-portal-server-moss-event-handlers.aspx) or [custom workflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scaravajal/archive/2006/11/13/sharepoint-2007-workflow-jumpstart.aspx) on source document library utilizing item added event.

Code is similar and here you have example:

[Move or Copy SharePoint Document Library Files Programmatically](http://geek.hubkey.com/2007/12/move-sharepoint-document-library-files.html)

Writing custom event handler would be my first pick. As far as I know there is no OOTB solution for this and most likely this cannot be done by SharePoint designer workflow (I am not very fond of workflows anyway).

Same applies to 2010 version.

Edited:

According to @Lars it can be done with SD so ignore that part of my answer.